# Page scope in jsp

Tags: jsp, pagecontext

I understand that page scope is the default scope in a jsp (least privileged as compared to request/session/application scope) and objects can be accessed only within the same jsp page.

I want to know if there is any possibility that two users accessing the same jsp page would share the object value that's been set at page scope? I highly feel that answer is No, but still want to confirm once.

In other terms does PageContext get shared between two users? If I set an object to page scope using pageContext.setAttribute(....), will this object be shared between two different users?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get a better understanding of how page scope works, by looking at how JSP page implementation classes use the `PageContext` object that represents said scope.

In the javadoc for package [javax.servlet.jsp](https://javaee.github.io/javaee-spec/javadocs/javax/servlet/jsp/package-summary.html) there is an example of how this is done.  The interesting part is:

```
public void _jspService(HttpServletRequest request,
                        HttpServletResponse response)
                        throws IOException, ServletException {

    JspFactory  factory     = JspFactory.getDefaultFactory();
    PageContext pageContext = factory.getPageContext( ... )

    ...
}
```

As you can see, when your servlet forwards its request and response objects to a JSP, the `_jspService` method of its page implementation class is invoked, taking them as arguments.  Right after, the method obtains a `PageContext` object and stores it as a **local variable** of the method.

Local variables are thread memory (not shared), and thus, there is no way for any other thread serving a request from another user (and not even from the same user) to get access to that variable.  Once `_jspService` returns, the variable simply ceases to exist.  If another thread concurrently calls `_jspService()`, the factory gives it a different `PageContext` instance.

This leads to the question of whether the `PageContext` object obtained from the factory is always a new instance or one being reused.  This is implementation dependent, as explained in the answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9581227/what-is-the-lifecycle-of-a-jsp-pagecontext-object-is-it-threadsafe).  In the latter case, the container should ensure that it never hands the same instance to two different threads **at the same time** (otherwise concurrency problems would arise).

Notice that, before returning, `_jspService()` ensures that the `PageContext` object is "cleansed" of any state by calling releasePageContext() (see the `finally` block in the javadoc example).  This in turn calls [release()](https://javaee.github.io/javaee-spec/javadocs/javax/servlet/jsp/PageContext.html#release--) on the `PageContext`, with the effect of "releasing all internal references, and preparing the PageContext for potential reuse".  So, when pooled instances are used, each thread always gets a "clean" one.